# Can't delete a directory in Mac

Tags: macos, permissions, filesystems, file-permissions

We have a bundle myapp.component and inside it we have a 'Contents' directory with the following permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx  4 root  wheel  136 Mar 18 15:05 Contents
```

When I try to delete this directory using

```
rm -rf Contents
```

It fails with the reason

```
rm: Contents/Resources/myapp.rsrc: Permission denied
rm: Contents/Resources: Directory not empty
```

We do have permissions to delete the 'Contents' directory so why does it still fails?

Edit: If I move the bundle from /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Component to ~/tmp/ then It will delete the folder without any problems

Thank you

Comment: Could you check the permission and owner of that `myapp.rsrc` using `stat Contents/Resources/myapp.rsrc`?

Comment: Also, this probably belongs on superuser.com

Comment: If I move the bundle from /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Component to ~/tmp/ then It will delete the folder without any problems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have permission to delete `Contents`, but not `Contents/Resources/mypp.rsrc`. If you do `ls -l` on that you'll see some more restrictive permissions.

In any case, from an admin account, you can do:

```
sudo rm -rf Contents
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: This is part of our automatic update process so we cannot use sudo here

Answer (score 1):

The file is probably still open.

You can use the `lsof` command to list open files, and find out what's using them:

`lsof | grep "myapp\.rsrc"`

Will probably tell you about the program with that particular file open.

Comment: I run it and the file is not open by other processes, It used to work well so we're quite baffled here..